# std::out_of_range for C++ code

Tags: c++, string, runtime-error, outofrangeexception

I am having errors running this code. While executing it gives out an error like-

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>   what():  basic_string::substr

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "fix_nvt.h"
#include "group.h"
#include "modify.h"
#include "error.h"

using namespace LAMMPS_NS;
using namespace FixConst;
using namespace std;

 std::ifstream inFile;

double x,y,z;
string str_val;

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

FixNVT::FixNVT(LAMMPS *lmp, int narg, char **arg) :
  FixNH(lmp, narg, arg)
{
  if (!tstat_flag)
    error->all(FLERR,"Temperature control must be used with fix nvt");
  if (pstat_flag)
    error->all(FLERR,"Pressure control can not be used with fix nvt");

  // create a new compute temp style
  // id = fix-ID + temp

  int n = strlen(id) + 6;
  id_temp = new char[n];
  strcpy(id_temp,id);
  strcat(id_temp,"_temp");

  char **newarg = new char*[3];
  newarg[0] = id_temp;
  newarg[1] = group->names[igroup];
  newarg[2] = (char *) "temp";

  modify->add_compute(3,newarg);
  delete [] newarg;
  tflag = 1;
  printf("syracuse rocks\n\n\n");
  inFile.open("matrix.txt", ios::in);
  while(getline(inFile,str_val));
    {
  x = atof(str_val.substr(1,4).c_str());
  y = atof(str_val.substr(17,4).c_str());
  z = atof(str_val.substr(33,4).c_str());
  printf ("x = %f, y =%f, z=%f\n",x,y,z);
 }
  inFile.close();



}
```

Comment: Are you sure 1,17 and 33 are valid indexes for `str_val`?

Comment: Using a debugger, you could step into and see the values stored into str_val and verify what @NathanOliver just said above

Comment: The reason I wrote it is because it reads from a file. matrix.txt and the file has values which start from 1, 17 and 33 numbered columns. I believe that is format right? substr(where it begins,how much space to leave before the next).

Comment: @Peter look at this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

Comment: Here is a suggestion.  In your while loop put `if (str_val.size() < 37) std::cout << "string to small!!!\n";` as the first line.  Recompile and let me know if that outputs or not.

Comment: @NathanOliver it does says string too small. Can you please help me address the problem?

Comment: @NathanOliver I am reading the contents of a file that I print already and its named as matrix.txt. The file shows content, I am not sure what this error means

Comment: It means you have a line in your file that is not as bid as you expect.  Next step is to print out that line and see what it is.  Then you have to figure out how to parse it and all the other data with the same process.